# Projecting $facet output to an object

Tags: mongodb

I created an aggregation ending with a facet operation, producing the following result:

```
[
    {
        "all": [
            {
                "all": 6948
            }
        ],
        "none": [
            {
                "none": 207
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I need is an output like below:

```
{
    all: 6948,
    none: 207
}
```

I tried some $projections but couldn't get rid of the arrays outside and inside of the result. Is this possible with $project or should I try something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use project stage after facet as

```
{$project:{
   all:{$arrayElemAt:["$all.all",0]},
   none:{$arrayElemAt:["$none.none",0]},
}}
```

Comment: Very close but I can't still get rid of the outermost array. With your solution I get an array with a single object inside.

Comment: In js or your language just return array[0] position

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$all"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$none"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      all: "$all.all",
      none: "$none.none"
    }
  }
])
```

[check in mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nl1WPHy5AO_)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    $project: {
      all: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$all",
          0
        ]
      },
      none: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$none",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      all: "$all.all",
      none: "$none.none"
    }
  }
```